# How is frozenset equality implemented in Python?

Tags: python, cpython, frozenset

How is frozenset equality implemented in CPython? In particular, I want to know how individual elements in the fronzenset are compared with each other and their total time complexity.

I took a look at [set and frozenset difference in implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646007/set-and-frozenset-difference-in-implementation) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778365/5792721.

The answer in the second link covers steps before comparing individual elements in the set, but missing the actual comparison algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation in question can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1815-L1822). The algorithm goes something like this, given that we want to check if two `sets` `v` and `w` are equal:

1. Check if their sizes are equal. If they are not, return `false`.

This references the `size` attribute of the `PySetObject`, so it's a constant time operation.

2. Check if both `sets` are `frozensets`. If so, and their hashes are different, return `false`.

Again, this references the `hash` attribute of the `PySetObject`, which is a constant time operation. This is possible because `frozensets` are immutable objects and hence have their hashes calculated when they are created.

3. Check if `w` is a subset of `v`.

This is done by iterating through each element of `v` and checking if it is present in `w`.

The iteration must be performed over all of `v`, and is therefore at worst linear in its size (if a differing element is found in the last position).

Membership testing for `sets` in general takes constant time in the average case and linear time in the worst case; combining the two gives time linear in the size of `v` in the average case and time proportional to `len(v) * len(w)` in the worst case.

This is, in a sense, the average case of the worst case, since it assumes that the first two checks always return `true`. If your data only rarely tends to have equal-size `sets` which also have the same hashes but contain different objects, then in the average case the comparison will still run in constant time.

Comment: The hashes don't tell that the two objects are the same. They tell if they are different. If the hashes match, they are compared.

Comment: @DanD. You're right; I misread the code. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Both [set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob//530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/setobject.c#L2140) and [frozenset](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob//530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/setobject.c#L2238) use [the `set_richcompare()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob//530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/setobject.c#L1806) for equality tests. There's no difference here.

`set_richcompare()`, as the other answers mention, compares sizes and then hashes. Then, it [checks whether one is a subset of the other](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob//530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/setobject.c#L1822), which just loops over every element in set 1, and checks if it is in set 2. This check is otherwise identical to [checking whether an element is in a set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob//530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/setobject.c#L430). This is done by hash-table lookup, with a linear search over items with equal hashes. The complexity for the existence check is [O(1) amortized or O(len(s)) worst-case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set), so the check for `set_issubset()` has a complexity of O(len(s1)) amortized, or O(len(s1)*len(s2)) worst-case.